# Optimizing a nested statement

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to find the best way to break down a long list of clicks, into relevant tables related to various landers.

```
SELECT LANDER, COUNT(DISTINCT IP) AS CLICKS
FROM
(
    SELECT LANDER, USER_GROUP, IP
    FROM
    (
            SELECT LANDER USER_GROUP, IP, TIME FROM CLICKS_IN WHERE USER_GROUP = " . $_SESSION["KKGR"] . "
    )a
    WHERE TIME BETWEEN '" . date_format($sdate, 'Y/m/d') . "' AND '" . date_format($edate, 'Y/m/d') . "'
 )a
GROUP BY LANDER HAVING COUNT(*)>5 ORDER BY CLICKS DESC";
```

Is what I've come up with so far to get a list of unique clicks efficiently.  My 2 problems are that I would much rather write a prepared query if possible, but I have no idea how to do it with a nested SQL statement, and secondly I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this \ what problems this could cause long run. It's running significantly more efficiently than a simple SQL statement but I'm concerned that I might be buffering to much of the table into RAM once\if this scales.

Comment: for optimization: use an explain plan, always the first place to go. add the output (as text) to your question if you need help with interpreting it. most common issue with slowness is missing indexes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the nesting is necessary, and it may be interfering with MySQL's ability to use an index on the `TIME` column.

```
SELECT LANDER, COUNT(DISTINCT IP) AS CLICKS
FROM CLICKS_IN
WHERE USER_GROUP = " $_SESSION['KKGR'] . "
AND TIME BETWEEN '" . date_format($sdate, 'Y/m/d') . "' AND '" . date_format($edate, 'Y/m/d') . "'
GROUP BY LANDER
HAVING CLICKS > 5
ORDER BY CLICKS DESC
```

Comment: It's demonstrability running faster than a standard query.  I've tried it without the nesting and both from a testing and live standpoint and it's significantly more efficient. 

The nested query massively reduces the operations count on the search for a large table.

edit:  Just tested your query, and the nested version preformed significantly better.

Comment: Needs `INDEX(user_group, time)` _in that order_.